# How to import contents of a database into a new database with phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Inside my MySQL databases there are 15 tables. Each table currently contains nothing inside, here are the tables.

[image]

Now I have a folder on my PC which contains 15 files with the same name, as shown here.

[image]

Inside the file, I have this line at the top so It should import it into the already existing database if I'm correct.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS inventories;
```

However when I do import it, I always get errors. Here is the error I get when I try to import the inventories file from my PC to the new database.

I don't know how to fix this. I'm very new to SQL as well.

Comment: Here is the error I get for inventories: http://prntscr.com/7tj5w8

Comment: What is your table structure? It seems tables don't exist.

Comment: So  you have a DROP statement for the table, do you have a CREATE statement to create the table if it has been dropped? You should likely post the whole sql file or else we would just be guessing.

Comment: Just a suggestion, download HeidiSQL, free tool for mysql database it is easy to use for all kind of things like export, import, test etc.

Comment: Since this question was left at "I get errors", it can be classified as missing a [mcve], and thus is off-topic.